# Redirecting network traffic

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to redirect some traffic going out, so when asked for 1.1.1.1:2222 local machine instead goes to 2.2.2.2:3333

Whats the easiest way to accomplish this with the use of java ?

Best regards

hosts file on windows is NOT! an option

EDIT: 
The ip 1.1.1.1:2222 is an extenal IP(a server i do not own). Therefore i cannot create a simple socket server to redirect the traffic. I have to somehow change the packet direction

Also note that it is the **OUTGOING** part i want to redirect. A quick example would be if i ask for www.google.dk i get facebook

This has to be done from java.

Comment: what is your aim for doing this?

Comment: I don't think this question is related to programming. You should tune the network software, and the work depends on specific requirements. For example, your target IP has DNS name? Are you interested in some protocol specific (eg http) redirection? Why do you specify the ports if the servers are not under your control?

Comment: It is relavant because the actual server does not belong to you per your replies so you sound like you are doing something that is not really menat to be, maybe even illegal like phishing...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this kind of thing in Java.  Indeed, you generally can't do this thing in user-space applications at all.

If you are using a Linux platform, you could potentially configure `iptables` to intercept outgoing packets of a given type that are destined for a particular IP address / port, and rewrite the destination IP address.  However, this is really a system / network administration problem, not a programming problem.

As you can imagine, there are all sorts of nasty things that you could do if a non-privileged application could cause traffic to be rerouted.  You need root priviledge on Linux to change the iptables configs.

---

> This has to be done from java.

Well, unless you are asking about the application *redirecting its own requests*, it can't be done in Java / from Java.

(In the exceptional case, you could potentially do this by implementing a custom socket factory that opens connects to a different place to what the higher levels of your application code is asking for.  However, I don't think that is what you are asking for.)

Comment: based on his question, I assume it's on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be easily implemented with sockets, basically:

1. Open a ServerSocket on 1.1.1.1:2222
2. Open a Socket to 2.2.2.2:3333
3. Redirect the outputStream of the first to the inputstream of the second and viceversa

You have an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/RedirectsincomingTCPconnectionstootherhostsports.htm)

Comment: Updated question. You don't seem to understand where i'm getting at :) Although thanks for trying ;)

Comment: Then you cannot do something like that, and thanks God. You have to be in the middle of the communication somehow... Imagine the chaos on the internet if you could redirect all the traffic of servers you do not own...