# Redirect All Network Traffic

Tags: c#, network-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)

I'm programming a proxy application, which I want to handle all network connections.
I have already programmed the server and client applications, so now I only need to redirect network connections to it.

I searched a lot, and this is what I found:

```
//For sniffing the socket to capture the packets has to be a raw socket, with the
//address family being of type internetwork, and protocol being IP
mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

//Bind the socket to the selected IP address
mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(cmbInterfaces.Text), 0));

//Set the socket  options
mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,    //Applies only to IP packets
SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded,                    //Set the include the header
true);                                              //option to true

byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] {1, 0, 0, 0};
byte[] byOut = new byte[4]{1, 0, 0, 0}; //Capture outgoing packets
```

I'm not sure if this going to help me, since I cannot cancel the original request.  What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: no, i already did that, that's not the problem, i don't want to configure browser to send traffic to my application, i wan't to cache all connections..

Comment: So this is effectively _how to implement man-in-the-middle-attacks in C#_ ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10447274/1025391

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to be able to transparently intercept all network traffic is with a driver, which you aren't going to be able to do in c# for obvious reasons.  That said, it might be possible to use [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) as the kernel mode component and to do your application logic in c#.  There is already some [interop code](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) written to work with winpcap, though I haven't used it so can't say how stable and/or complete the support is.